# Generic reader for all formats?

Tags: java, json, xml, parsing

I would like to know if there is some possible way to create a generic reader that can read XML or JSON messages without having to check what type of message it is and write a reader for each of them.

Comment: If it's just JSON and XML you might be able to use something like JaxB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three techniques are typically used to parse messages of multiple possible formats:

1. **Declaration**: Be told the format via a parameter or header value. [**Preferred**]
2. **Sniffing**: Lexically scan ahead into the stream to identify the format.
3. **Fallback**: Try parsing under one format, and fallback to the other if parsing fails.

For #1 or #2, once message type is determined, the message is dispatched to the appropriate parser.  A single, homogenous parser is usually not used for two distinctly different formats such as XML and JSON.

#3 is generally inefficient but may be viable for small messages or throw-away code.

Comment: What I have at the moment is a validator for JSON and XML implemented, but the issue is I don't know if the message that comes through is going to be inserted into the the database into another format like commma separated text. So I need something that can read everything into a generic format or create a validator process to check what the format is.

Comment: So #1 is not possible for you; you're left with #2 or #3.   Also, you have a design decision regarding whether to distribute your validation checks across formats or convert to a core format and validate centrally.  This is about as much as I can say without knowing a lot more about your use cases, and StackOverflow isn't the forum for addressing broad design decisions.  Hope I've helped at least a bit with upfront considerations.